# Help me calculate a probability

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X$ is a random variable that follows $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.
I need to calculate the probabilities of type I and type II errors of the statistical hypotheses : $$H_{0}: μ=125$$ $$H_{1}: μ\neq125$$
The book takes the critical region $K=[x\in\mathbb R^n: |\bar x-125|>c]$.

Then it goes on to find the probability of type I error

$$α=Pr[|\bar X-125|>c | μ=125]$$ and type II error $$β=Pr[|\bar X-125|<c | μ\neq125]$$

I know that from here we create the standard normal distribution but can you explain me how to calculate probabilities that have absolute values in them? My guess is that you break the probability into two, but for example in the following
$$Pr[|\bar X-125|>c | μ=125]$$ how do I deal with the absolute value since it's not $|\bar X-125|<c$ but $|\bar X-125|>c$ ? If it was the second I could type $-c<\bar X-125<c$.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: "If it was the second I could type $−c<\bar X −125<c$." First, to clarify, you mean if it was $|\bar X - 125| < c$. Then use the fact that $|\bar X - 125| > c$ and $|\bar X - 125| < c$ are complementary events since you have a continuous random variable.

Comment: That much is easy: $P(|\bar X-125| > c) = 1 - P(|\bar X-125| < c).$ [You are dealing with a continuous (normal) distribution, so $=c$ doesn't matter.]

Comment: So i can just calculate one probability and then multiply it by 2?